# Why does TCanvas not draw during the execution of a macro in the root shell?

Tags: c++, root-framework, tcanvas

Suppose I have a macro that contains two **TGraphs**: **T1** and **T2** and I have a canvas "**C**" divided into two parts:

```
TCanvas *C = new TCanvas("","",0,0,400,400);
C->Divide(2,1);
```

when this part gets executed the blanc canvas appears on my screen but it's grayed out.. inactive! But that's okay, then it proceeds..

The program has two distinct parts, in the first part it completes calculations enters the first half of the canvas and draws the first **TGraph**:

```
C->cd(1);
T1->Draw("AP");
```

at this point I expect to already see the graph on the first half of the canvas but unfortunately nothing appears, the canvas remains inactive! The program proceeds to the next part:

```
C->cd(2);
T2->Draw("AP");
```

same story nothing appears on the canvas yet, but then the execution finishes and I am back to the root shell as in like this:

```
root[#]
```

and now I can see the two graphs! What I want is that the parts that have been executed like `T1->Draw("AP")` should already appear on the `cd(1)` and then later the graph on `cd(2)` should appear. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: In relation to commenting on meta-issues, it is probably better if you do this in the comments, since it is not really of interest to most readers (who do not sign in or vote on questions). Readers very much prefer succinct here!

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found a solution in the CERN-ROOT's thread:

https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=13082

where the user "couet" suggested to use

`C->Modified();
 C->Update();`

after each "`C->Draw();`"

I applied this to my problem and it worked.